# How to send questionId and answer of user to controller using ajax in asp.net core

Tags: jquery, ajax, asp.net-core

I'm trying to save questionIds and user's answers to a class that contains dictonary using ajax.
This is the ViewModel class:

```
 public class AnswersVM
{
  public List<Dictionary<int, string>> group { get; set; }
  public List<Dictionary<int, string>> trueFalse { get; set; }
}
```

This is the view:

```
<form id="QuestionsForm" asp-action="SubmitAnswers" asp-controller="Home" method="post" 
      enctype="multipart/form-data">
@foreach (var item in Model)
{
    <div class="col-lg-6">
            <p>
                <!--choice-->

                @if (item.choiceQuestionSelection.Any(q => q.QuestionId == item.QuestionId))
                {
                    foreach (var correct in item.choiceQuestionSelection.Where(q => q.QuestionId == 
                 item.QuestionId && q.IsTrue == true).Select(q => q.Choice))
                    {
                        <input type="hidden" data-correct="@i" value="@correct" />
                        <input type="hidden" name="group[@i]" value="@item.QuestionId" />
                    }
                    @foreach (var choice in item.choiceQuestionSelection)
                    {
                        <label>
                            <input type="radio" data-choice="@i" name="group[@i]" class="group" 
                   value="@choice.Choice">@choice.Choice
                        </label>
                    }

                    i++;

                }
                else
                @if (item.trueFalseQuestions.Any(q => q.QuestionId == item.QuestionId))
                {
                    <!--truefalse-->
                    foreach (var rightChoice in item.trueFalseQuestions.Where(q => q.QuestionId == 
               item.QuestionId).Select(q => q.IsTrue))
                    {
                        var convertRightChoice = Convert.ToString(rightChoice);
                        <input type="hidden" value="@convertRightChoice" data-true="@trueFalse" />
                        <input type="hidden" name="QIdTrueFalse[@trueFalse]" value="@item.QuestionId" 
                   />
                    }
                    @foreach (var question in item.trueFalseQuestions)
                    {
                        var convertToString = Convert.ToString(question.IsTrue);
                        <label>
                            <input type="radio" data-selection="@(trueFalse)" 
                name="trueFalse[@trueFalse]" class="trueFalse" value="صحیح">صحیح
                        </label>

                        <label>
                            <input type="radio" data-selection="@(trueFalse)" 
             name="trueFalse[@trueFalse]" class="trueFalse" value="غلط">غلط
                        </label>

                    }
                    trueFalse++;
                }
                else
                {
                    <input type="hidden" name="QIdDescriptive[@descriptive]" value="@item.QuestionId" 
                             />
                    <textarea class="descriptive" name="Descriptive" id="descriptive" 
         placeholder="پاسخ شما..."></textarea>
                    descriptive++;
                }
    
            </p>
        </div>
    </div>
    QuestionCount++;

  }
  <input type="submit" id="submitButton" name="submitButton" value="ارسال">
 </form>
```

this is my controller:

```
 [HttpPost]
    public string SubmitAnswers(AnswersVM userAnswers)
    {

        return "success";
    }
```

and this is the ajax:

```
    $('#QuestionsForm').submit(function (event) {
        event.preventDefault();
        var frm = $(this);
        console.log(frm);
        console.log(frm.serialize());
        $.ajax({
            url: frm.attr('action'),
            method: "POST",
            data: frm.serialize(),

        }).done(function (res) {
            alert(res)
        });

    });
```

sorry I really tried to figure it out by myself based on my previous questions but I couldn't find out the answer and I need help.
when I run this I get null in controller.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`List<Dictionary<int, string>>` need the type of `group[@i][@item.QuestionId]`. The first `[]` indicates the index of List, the second `[]` indicates the key of Dictionary.

Change it the view.

```
@model IEnumerable<Question>
@{
  ViewData["Title"] = "ShowQuestions";
  Layout = "~/Views/Shared/_Layout.cshtml";
  var QuestionCount = 1;
  var i = 0;
  var trueFalse = 0;
  var descriptive = 0;
 }
<form id="QuestionsForm" asp-action="SubmitAnswers" asp-controller="Home" method="post"
  enctype="multipart/form-data">
@foreach (var item in Model)
{
    <div class="col-lg-6">
        <p>
            <!--choice-->

            @if (item.choiceQuestionSelection.Any(q => q.QuestionId == item.QuestionId))
            {
                foreach (var correct in item.choiceQuestionSelection.Where(q => q.QuestionId ==
                item.QuestionId && q.IsTrue == true).Select(q => q.Choice))
                {
                    <input type="hidden" data-correct="@i" value="@correct" />
                    @*<input type="hidden" name="group[@i0][]" value="@item.QuestionId" />*@
                }
                @foreach (var choice in item.choiceQuestionSelection)
                {
                    <label>
                        <input type="radio" data-choice="@i" name="group[@i][@item.QuestionId]" class="group"
                               value="@choice.Choice">@choice.Choice
                        </label>
                }

                i++;

            }
            else
            @if (item.trueFalseQuestions.Any(q => q.QuestionId == item.QuestionId))
            {
                <!--truefalse-->
                foreach (var rightChoice in item.trueFalseQuestions.Where(q => q.QuestionId ==
           item.QuestionId).Select(q => q.IsTrue))
                {
                    var convertRightChoice = Convert.ToString(rightChoice);
                    <input type="hidden" value="@convertRightChoice" data-true="@trueFalse" />
                    <input type="hidden" name="QIdTrueFalse[0][@trueFalse]" value="@item.QuestionId" />
                }
                @foreach (var question in item.trueFalseQuestions)
                {
                    var convertToString = Convert.ToString(question.IsTrue);
                    <label>
                        <input type="radio" data-selection="@(trueFalse)"
                               name="trueFalse[0][@trueFalse]" class="trueFalse" value="صحیح">صحیح
                    </label>

                    <label>
                        <input type="radio" data-selection="@(trueFalse)"
                               name="trueFalse[@trueFalse]" class="trueFalse" value="غلط">غلط
                    </label>

                }
                trueFalse++;
            }
            else
            {
                <input type="hidden" name="QIdDescriptive[@descriptive]" value="@item.QuestionId" />
                <textarea class="descriptive" name="Descriptive" id="descriptive"
                          placeholder="پاسخ شما..."></textarea>
                descriptive++;
            }

        </p>
    </div>
    
    QuestionCount++;

}
<input type="submit" id="submitButton" name="submitButton" value="ارسال">
</form>
```

Then you can get the data as below.

[image]

Comment: Thank's but actually I need to get the value of the selected choice in dictionary. instead of "1" I want it to show "choice3".

Comment: @nikitmb, now you can refer to the edited answer which contains the value.

Comment: @nikitmb, you are welome. Another method is to use this type `group[@i].@item.QuestionId`. It can correspond to the index of array and the key of dictionary.

Comment: Is there any way to use the real questionId as the index of dictionary?[@i] is the counter that I made.

Comment: @nikitmb, `[@i]` is the index of list,and `.@item.QuestionId` is the key of dictionary.